# Create table from values for a bar chart

Tags: r

I have three values.

```
Person1 <- 21
Person2 <- 22
Person3 <- 25
```

Is it possible to create a table in the following format from three values?

```
    Person  Age
1   Person1 21
2   Person2 22
3   Person3 25
```

I need this output, because I will build a Bar Chart.

I tried using a data.frame but did not get the desired result.

```
data <- data.frame(Person1, Person2, Person3)
```

I would be very pleased about support.
Thanks, Jeem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just bind them together with `rbind`, convert to a `data.frame` and turn the `rownames` into a column, if you desire.

```
df <- as.data.frame(rbind(Person1, Person2, Person3))

df$person <- rownames(df)
colnames(df) <- c('Age', 'Person')

df
        Age  Person
Person1 21  Person1
Person2 22  Person2
Person3 25  Person3
```